# Regex with NancyFx Routes

Tags: regex, routes, nancy

I'm trying to create generic route for category page,

My current Regex for evaluation,

```
\/[\w\/\-\%]+-c(\d+)(?:\/(\d{1,2}))?$
```

Controller code,

```
Get[@"\/[\w\/\-\%]+-c(?<id>\d+)(?:\/(?<page>\d{1,2}))?$", true] = async (x, ct) =>
{
  ...
}
```

I'm trying with RegExr tool and it seems to be passing all possible permutation and combinations for the regex,

```
i.e /anytgc123423/test/c123323/niec454stest/mystery-123-4534-thriller-suspense-c79/11

Result:
Group 1: 79 
Group 2: 11
```

The same regex is not able to parse the url suggested in example with NancyFx Get function.

It would be great help if anyone can throw some light.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes

Routes are picked up using `(` and `)` for regular expressions.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Routing/Trie/TrieNodeFactory.cs#L38

```
        if (start == '(' && end == ')')
        {
            return new RegExNode(parent, segment, this);
        }
```

So your route wont work unless you wrap it with braces.

In your case you want to use a Greedy Regex which is done using `^(` and `)$`

```
        if (segment.StartsWith("^(") && (segment.EndsWith(")") || segment.EndsWith(")$")))
        {
            return new GreedyRegExCaptureNode(parent, segment, this);
        }
```